# Kivy: How to check for the existence of a child widget

Tags: python, python-3.x, kivy, kivy-language

In my .py file I have a screen that looks something like:

```
class ExampleScreen(Screen):
    def create_layout(self):
        box = BoxLayout(orientation='vertical')
        # other layout stuff in here
        self.add_widget(box)
```

In my .kv file, I have a button which, when pressed, calls this function and displays this layout on `<ExampleScreen>`. However, I would like to be able to press this button and first check if this layout already exists, and if so, *remove* it before adding a new one. I anticipate modifying `create_layout()` to something like:

```
def create_layout(self):
    if (box layout child has already been added):
        self.remove_widget(box layout child)
    box = BoxLayout(orientation='vertical')
    # other layout stuff in here
    self.add_widget(box)
```

Does anyone know how to do this? Using `id` somehow?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Each widget has a *children* property so you may want to use it.

```
for c in list(self.children):
    if isinstance(c, BoxLayout): self.remove(c)
```

You can also assign it to the widget: (as mentioned in Edvardas Dlugauskas anwser)

```
def __init__(self, **kw):
    self.box = None
    ...


def create_layout(self):
    if self.box: self.remove(self.box) 
    self.box = BoxLayout(orientation='vertical')
    self.add_widget(box)
```

Answer (score -1):

Well, you can do it with an id or some other child checks, but the easiest and most straight-forward way would be to have a boolean flag in your class that would change to `True` when you added the widget and `False` when you removed it. Otherwise, you can also create a kivy `box_obj = ObjectProperty(None)` and do `self.box_obj = box` and then check if the `self.box_obj` is not None.

Comment: @YoavGlazner yes, but neither are any actual children checks if we judge by the example OP gave us. Sorry, I'm just used to using kivy properties - they're so undervalued in my opinion. I wonder if they have much overhead if used instead of regular Python attributes, do you happen to know?

Comment: for this use-case they are a bit heavier since they use the **descriptor protocol** - https://docs.python.org/3.6/howto/descriptor.html - they are implemented in cython, though.